# Menu dont stick in panel on scroll and moves

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, position

I am facing very strange issue, this is the html url on which i am working:
[My Website Link](http://198.50.129.105/sodic/%60)
when i scroll the page little bit the menu moves downward.

I want to to stick menu all the time along with buttons in blue panel it is working 80% but at start it moves with the scroll and then it does not.

any one guide me what is the issue to stop menu movement on start of the scroll?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised that someone with 15k+ rep don't know how to ask a question here properly.

Comment: With so much rep, you should know how to ask a relevant question, including minimalistic sample to replicate issue (and btw how to post link in question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove fixed style for .side-wrapper .side-nav

```
.side-wrapper .side-nav {
  /* position: fixed; */
  width: 46px;
}
```

main.css line 4740